# How can i play mp3 from Resource using nAudio in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, naudio

I'm using [nAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com) to play a background song in my WPF Application.
Now to start a new instace of a song the code to is this:

```
        private WaveStream CreateInputStream(string fileName)
    {
        WaveChannel32 inputStream;
        if (fileName.EndsWith(".mp3"))
        {
            WaveStream mp3Reader = new Mp3FileReader(fileName);
            inputStream = new WaveChannel32(mp3Reader);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported extension");
        }
        volumeStream = inputStream;
        return volumeStream;
    }
```

Which works fine, but **only** to a specific file path.
Now if i try sending a Pack URL to this function, i get error that the format isn't supported.
Anyone ever encouterd this and knows what i should do?

**SOLVED :**
thanks to minitech answer, this code eventully worked :

```
 StreamResourceInfo resource = Application.GetResourceStream(
          new Uri("YearBook;component/Resources/Music/1.mp3", UriKind.Relative));
        mainOutputStream = CreateInputStream(resource.Stream);
        waveOutDevice.Init(mainOutputStream);


    private WaveStream CreateInputStream(Stream fileName)
    {
        WaveChannel32 inputStream;
        WaveStream mp3Reader = new Mp3FileReader(fileName);
        inputStream = new WaveChannel32(mp3Reader);
        volumeStream = inputStream;
        return volumeStream;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Mp3FileReader` constructor is overloaded to take a stream. I don't know how WPF resources work, but if you can get your file as a `Stream` object somehow, then you can use that. Here's how you can play a `byte[]`:

```
private WaveStream CreateInputStream(byte[] resource) {
    WaveChannel32 inputStream;

    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(resource)) {
        WaveStream mp3Reader = new Mp3FileReader(ms);
        inputStream = new WaveChannel32(mp3Reader);
    }

    return inputStream;
}
```

Comment: I can get is as stream, but i don't understand how i can insert it, it says that it expects string

Comment: Eric can you please tell me how you fixed it